# What is "#" (number sign) in Data.Validation examples?

Tags: haskell

From [Data.Validation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-0.5.4/docs/Data-Validation.html):

> ```
> >>> _Success # (+1) <*> _Success # 7 :: AccValidation String Int
> AccSuccess 8
> ```

What is the `#`/number sign/pound sign/hash sign/octothorp in the above example?

Comment: The [page you link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-0.5.4/docs/Data-Validation.html) contains a [source link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-0.5.4/docs/src/Data-Validation.html#AccValidation) that contains the line `import Control.Lens.Review(( # ))` that can easily answer where it comes from, it takes little more effort to find the actual documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from the lens library: `import Control.Lens.Review(( # ))`

See [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Review.html#v:-35-)